# Swift Spritekit apply rotational impulse

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am making a space shooter game with Swift and SpriteKit I would like that when the user presses a key, the ship will rotate. Currently I rotate the node, However, I would like to apply a physics impulse to rotate the nodes physics body, So it will continue rotating when I release the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
node.physicsBody?.applyAngularImpulse
```

or:

```
node.physicsBody?.angularVelocity
```